# How to generate random number that must contains predefined characters?

Tags: php

In my application i need to generate random numbers that should contain certain character like capital letter, a number and of certain length.
It will be an honor if you guys help me out.

Comment: Generate arrays/lists of characters that you want to require (one for lower, one for upper, one for numbers...etc). Pick however many characters you want from each list and join them together.

Comment: You should not just simply join them, though. You should a) randomize the number of characters you take from each list (ensuring the required minimum amount from each list), then *shuffle* the results together so that a hacker doesn't know you first have the lower case, then the upper case, then the numbers.

Comment: post what have you tried please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a script that requires the word "Lock" followed by a 2 digit number followed by a random four-letter word. This is an abbreviation of what I used...

```
$words = array("Pick","Hard","Gene","Boat","Pass");
// Make that list as long as you like...
function get_random_string()
{
    global $words;
    shuffle($words);
    return 'Lock'.rand(10,99).$words[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function rand_string( $length ) {

    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    return substr(str_shuffle($chars),0,$length);

}

echo rand_string(8);
```